# Find duplicates inside of import and a global database with Apache Beam

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-beam

## Goal

I have the task to find duplicate entries within import files, and in a later stage duplicate entries of these import files compared to a global database. The data inside of the files are personal information like name, email, address etc. The data is not always complete, and often spelled incorrectly.

The files will be uploaded by external users through a web form. The user needs to be notified when the process is done, and he / she has to be able to download the results.

Additionally to solving this task I need to assess the suitability of Apache Beam for this task.

## Possible solution

I was thinking about the following: The import files are uploaded to S3, and the pipeline will either get the file location as a pub-sub event (Kafka queue), or watch S3 (if possible) for incoming files.

Then the file is read by one PTransform and each line is pushed into a PCollection. As a side output I would update a search index (inside Redis or some such). The next transform would access the search index, and tries to find matches. The end result (unique value, duplicate values) are written to an output file to S3, and the index is cleared for the next import.

## Questions

- Does this approach make sense - is it idiomatic for Beam?
- Would Beam be suitable for this processing?
- Any improvement suggestions for the above?
- I would need to track the file name / ID to notify the user at the end. How can I move this meta-data through the pipeline. Do I need to create an "envelope" object for meta-data and payload, and use this object in my PCollection?
- The incoming files are unbounded, but the file contents itself are bounded. Is there a way to find out the end of the file processing in an idiomatic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this approach make sense - is it idiomatic for Beam?

This is a subjective question. In general, I would say no, this is not idiomatic for Apache Beam. Apache Beam is a framework for defining ETL pipelines. The Beam programming model has no opinions or builtin functionality for deduplicating data. Deduplication is achieved through implementation (business logic code you write) or a feature of a data store (UNIQUE constraint, SELECT DISTINCT in SQL or key/value storage).

> Would Beam be suitable for this processing?

Yes, Beam is suitable.

> Any improvement suggestions for the above?

I do not recommend writing to a search index in the middle of the pipeline. By doing this and then attempting to read the data back in the following transform, you've effectively created a cycle in the DAG. The pipeline may suffer from race conditions. It is less complex to have two separate pipelines - one to write to the search index (deduplicate) and a second one to write back to S3.

> I would need to track the file name / ID to notify the user at the end. How can I move this meta-data through the pipeline. Do I need to create an "envelope" object for meta-data and payload, and use this object in my PCollection?

Yes, this is one approach. I believe you can get the file metadata via [ReadableFile](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.ReadableFile.html) class.

> The incoming files are unbounded, but the file contents itself are bounded. Is there a way to find out the end of the file processing in an idiomatic way?

I'm not sure off the top, but I don't think this is possible for a pipeline executing in streaming mode.